How do I resolve the following dependency issues?
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 10), -r requirements.txt (line 15), intriniorealtime==2.2.0 and requests==2.20.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:

The user requested requests==2.20.0
coreapi 2.3.3 depends on requests
django-allauth 0.40.0 depends on requests
intriniorealtime 2.2.0 depends on requests==2.19.1

To fix this you could try to:

loosen the range of package versions you've specified
remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

My requirements.txt file for python django.
amqp         ==2.5.2
anyjson      ==0.3.3
astroid      ==2.4.2
billiard     ==3.6.1.0
celery       ==4.4.0
certifi      ==2019.9.11
cffi         ==1.14.0
chardet      ==3.0.4
colorama     ==0.4.3
coreapi      ==2.3.3
coreschema   ==0.0.4
cryptography ==2.8
defusedxml           ==0.6.0
Django               ==2.2.6
django-allauth       ==0.40.0
django-appconf       ==1.0.6
django-base-url      ==2019.7.24
django-compat        ==1.0.15
django-cors-headers  ==3.7.0
django-crispy-forms  ==1.7.2
django-crontab       ==0.7.1
django-cryptography  ==1.1
django-markdown-deux ==1.0.5
django-pagedown      ==0.1.1
django-rest-auth          ==0.9.5
django-rest-passwordreset ==1.0.0
django-rest-swagger       ==2.2.0
django-timezone-field     ==4.0
django-unique-slugify     ==1.1
djangorestframework       ==3.9.4
djangorestframework-jwt   ==1.8.0
future                    ==0.18.2
idna                      ==2.7
importlib-metadata        ==1.3.0
intrinio-sdk              ==5.0.1
intriniorealtime          ==2.2.0
isort                     ==4.3.21
itypes                    ==1.1.0
Jinja2                    ==2.10.3
kombu                     ==4.6.7
lazy-object-proxy         ==1.4.3
markdown2                 ==2.3.8
MarkupSafe                ==1.1.1
mccabe                    ==0.6.1
more-itertools            ==8.0.2
mysqlclient               ==1.4.6
numpy                     ==1.18.1
oauthlib                  ==3.1.0
openapi-codec             ==1.3.2
packaging                 ==19.2
pandas                    ==1.0.2
paypalrestsdk             ==1.13.1
Pillow                    ==7.0.0
pip                       ==19.2.3
pycparser                 ==2.19
pyfcm                     ==1.4.7
PyJWT                     ==1.4.0
pylint                    ==2.5.3
pyOpenSSL                 ==19.1.0
pyparsing                 ==2.4.2
python-crontab            ==2.4.0
python-dateutil           ==2.8.1
python-http-client        ==3.2.7
python3-openid            ==3.1.0
pytz                      ==2019.3
redis                     ==3.3.11
requests                  ==2.20.0
requests-oauthlib         ==1.2.0
schedule                  ==0.6.0
sendgrid                  ==6.2.2
setuptools                ==41.2.0
simplejson                ==3.16.0
six                       ==1.12.0
sqlparse                  ==0.3.0
stripe                    ==2.44.0
toml                      ==0.10.1
uritemplate               ==3.0.0
urllib3                   ==1.23
vine                      ==1.3.0
websocket-client          ==0.48.0
whitenoise                ==5.0.1
wrapt                     ==1.12.1
zipp                      ==0.6.0

I have tried removing intrino to changing request ==2.20.0 to requests but still didnt work and then I tried upgrading intrino version that can use request 2.20 or greater to make it compatible or completely remove intrinorealtime then it gives me the following error
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
C:\Users\jaina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt

which I think indicates that there are missing dependencies, no matter what I do from downgrading to upgrading dependency to resolve my issue,
I always end up with
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
C:\Users\jaina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt 

above error in the end. Can someone help?

You should likely consider upgrading your version of initriniorealtime; 2.2.0 was released in 2019: https://github.com/intrinio/intrinio-realtime-python-sdk/releases/tag/2.2.0

This is happening because you are trying to install a package version that is not supported by other packages in your environment. So as it suggests, don't try to install with a specific version.
Just remove "==2.20.0" after "requests" and it will figure out which version needs to be installed on its own.
